# Enum to return an implementation of an interface

Tags: java, spring, enums

I have an interface called `HeaderProvider` and its implementations like this,

```
interface HeaderProvider {
    Map<String, String> getHeaders();
}

class AHeaderProvider implements HeaderProvider {
...
}
class BHeaderProvider implements HeaderProvider {
...
}
```

The implementations are Spring managed beans. Now I have an enum URLType

```
enum URLType{
A,
B....
}
```

Is there any way I can have a method inside the enum like `HeaderProvider getHeaderProvider()` which will return the correct implementation?

Comment: Sounds like you want a Factory Method?

Comment: I have a factory method already, but that resulted in two separate methods.
1. parse URL to find out which type of URL it is,
2. use URLType to get correct implementation of HeaderProvider.

I feel that the problem with this approach is that if any new implementation if required it has to be handled in multiple places instead of one. So I was thinking if we can organize them into a single place.

Answer (score 0):

Just add a `HeaderProvider` member to the [enum](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/enum.html)

```java
public enum URLType {
    A(new AHeaderProvider()), B(new BHeaderProvider());

    private HeaderProvider provider;

    private URLType(HeaderProvider provider) {
        this.provider = provider;
    }

    public HeaderProvider getHeaderProvider() {
        return provider;
    }
}
```

Comment: since the implementations are spring managed beans, shouldn't we use spring DI for their initialization?

Answer (score 0):

I think you can do like this.

```java
@Component
public class AHeaderProvider implements HeaderProvider, InitializingBean {

    private static HeaderProvider headerProvider;

    public static HeaderProvider getHeaderProvider() {
        return headerProvider;
    }

    @Override
    public void afterPropertiesSet() throws Exception {
        headerProvider = this;
    }

    @Override
    public Map<String, String> getHeaders() {
        return new HashMap<>();
    }
}

@Component
public class BHeaderProvider implements HeaderProvider, InitializingBean {

    private static HeaderProvider headerProvider;

    public static HeaderProvider getHeaderProvider() {
        return headerProvider;
    }

    @Override
    public void afterPropertiesSet() throws Exception {
        headerProvider = this;
    }

    @Override
    public Map<String, String> getHeaders() {
        return new HashMap<>();
    }
}

public enum UrlType {

    A(AHeaderProvider.getHeaderProvider()),

    B(BHeaderProvider.getHeaderProvider());
    private HeaderProvider headerProvider;

    UrlType(HeaderProvider headerProvider) {
        this.headerProvider = headerProvider;
    }


    public HeaderProvider getHeaderProvider() {
        return headerProvider;
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you @qinghua. I was looking for something like this.